# Connection is lost when fetching data from the database

Tags: r, r-dbi

I have a function that fetches data from a mysql server.  I do this using formulas like this:

```
sql <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM `match_player` INNER JOIN `match` ON match_player.match_id=match.id")
df_all <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

It all works. However I have to perform calculation over +/- 200.000 rows and for each of the rows I have to fetch data from the database. And after +/- 100.000 records I get an error cause the connection is lost:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :    could not run statement:
>   Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Any thoughts on how i can make sure I do not lose the connection

Comment: try changing wait_timeout and interactive_timeout in my.cnf on your server and check if the issue is in fact of timeout.

Comment: You can query in chunks [see page 9](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Delayed, but perhaps helpful: This looks like a known regression in recent DBI and RMySQL versions, possibly fixable with a downgrade: https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/190